# Orient DB - Export subclasses of a specified class using JAVA

Tags: java, export, orientdb

Im working with exporting and importing Orient DB using java. I could export a whole database. But when i specify to export a specified class it export that class only. Sub classes are not exported. Here is the code:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/sampleDataBase").open("admin", "admin");

ODatabaseExport export = new ODatabaseExport(db, "DataCont/FinalTry.gz", listener);

Set<String> a= new HashSet<String>();
a.add("Employee".toUpperCase());

export.setIncludeClasses(a);

export.exportDatabase();
export.close();
```

So is this suppose to be or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the source code for [ODatabaseExport](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/tool/ODatabaseExport.java) it does seem that it only takes clusters/records which are exactly of the type specified with `setIncludeClasses()`. For instance in `exportRecords()`:

```
 ODocument doc = (ODocument) rec;
 final String className = doc.getClassName() != null ? doc.getClassName().toUpperCase() : null;
 if (includeClasses != null) {
     if (!includeClasses.contains(className))
         continue;
 } else if (excludeClasses != null) {
     if (excludeClasses.contains(className))
         continue;
 }
```

They have similar checks in several other places in that class. This would mean that you need to put into the `a` set all the classes you want to export yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this piece of code if want to export all subclasses too:

```
        Set<String> classesToExport = new HashSet<>();
        classesToExport.add("Employee".toUpperCase());

        OSchema oSchema = db.getMetadata().getSchema();
        for (String className : classesToExport) {
            OClass clazz = oSchema.getClass(className);
            for(OClass subClass : clazz.getAllBaseClasses()){
                //String subClassName = subClass.getName();
                String subClassName = subClass.getName().toUpperCase();
                if(!classesToExport.contains(subClassName)){
                    classesToExport.add(subClassName);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: one `.toUpperCase()` missing, sorry. See the update.

Comment: Small question: Is this for abstract class sub class or class with links of other classes? Thanks for your time...

Comment: Not links. For example, if this is the case: `create class subEmployee extends Employee; create class subsubEmployee extends subEmployee;` it would export Employee, subEmployee and subsubEmployee.

Comment: Oh. I thought its for links also. Found a workaround. Find the classes which are not being used and exclude them. My db is not that big. So it wont be a problem. Thanks for the help anyway.